# Does a MaterialComponents ImageButton exist?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-imagebutton

I am converting my app from `AppCompat` to `MaterialComponents`.

I have come across an issue that there is no theme under `Widget.MaterialComponents.` that applies to `ImageButton`.

Here is an example of one of my ImageButtons:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:tint="@color/shape_orange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape" />
```

How would I achieve the `MaterialComponents` look for an `ImageButton`? I would like to achieve the `.OutlinedButton` style for the `ImageButton`

Answer (score 1):

Currently in v1.1.0, there's no `MaterialImageView` or `MaterialImageButton`.

But in v1.2.0, there's `ShapeableImageView` coming out which extends `AppCompatImageView`

About the `ImageView` you can use the `ShapeableImageView` which extends the `AppCompatImageView.`

You can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/customImageViewRounded"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/...."
```

with:

```
 <style name="customImageViewRounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>

    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```